# Is it possible to determine the Win32_DiskDrive SerialNumber of the Environment.SpecialFolder.System drive?

Tags: c#, windows, wmi, hard-drive

I've been going around in circles for a bit now, can't seem to find the answer on google either.

As the title says, if i get the current drive letter windows is running on, let's say like this: `Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System));`
Can i then determine its Win32_DiskDrive SerialNumber? I cannot find a way to link them.

That is the manufacturer's S/N not the VolumeSerialNumber.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @HansPassant I understand that, my question is whether or not it is possible to determine which physical drive a drive letter/volume relates to? Is there any way to link a drive letter to its physical drive's Win32_DiskDrive SerialNumber?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ManagmentObjectSearch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementobjectsearcher?view=netframework-4.8) combined with [ASSOCIATORS OF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/associators-of-statement) statement:

```
public static string GetSerialNumber(string logicalDrive)
{
    using (var partitionsQuery = new ManagementObjectSearcher(string.Format("ASSOCIATORS OF {{Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID='{0}'}} WHERE ResultClass = Win32_DiskPartition", logicalDrive)))            
    {
        foreach (var results in partitionsQuery.Get())
        {
            using (var diskDrives = new ManagementObjectSearcher(string.Format("ASSOCIATORS OF {{Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='{0}'}} WHERE ResultClass=Win32_DiskDrive", results["DeviceID"])))
            {
                foreach (var d in diskDrives.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Serial: " + d["SerialNumber"]);

                    return d["SerialNumber"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
var num = GetSerialNumber(Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory).TrimEnd(new [] {'\\'}));
```

Note: Dont forget to remove backslashes from the path returned by `Path.GetPathRoot`.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ManagementObjectSearcher class from System.Management then loop through the properties to find the serial number.

I think something along these lines will get you close to what you're looking for...

```
                var search = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_DiskDrive");
                foreach (var mo in search.Get())
                {
                    if (mo["SerialNumber"] != null)
                    {
                        return mo["SerialNumber"].ToString();
                    }
                }
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-diskdrive

^ that should contain all the various properties you can get

Hope that helps.