# Serial number of the system disk

Tags: windows, wmi

I want to find the serial number of the system disk of a Windows machine, by program.

I am familiar with the WMI services and I am able to retrieve the system drive (`SystemDrive` from `Win32_OperatingSystem`), also the serial number of all disks (`SerialNumber` from `Win32_DiskDrive`), among others. But I am looking for a simple way to make the connection and find the serial just for the system disk.

Any hint ?

Comment: How about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57559814/1410246

Comment: @EylM: maybe. The approach seems to play with logical disks and disk partitions. I am missing a clear view of the interrelations.

Comment: Win32_DiskDrive  is a physical disk. System drive (lets say c:\) is a logical drive. So you need a way to connect physical to logical. (this is the link in my comment).