# Get drive serial number for a specific drive

Tags: winapi, wmi, drive

I would like to get the drive serial number where the AppData folder is located.

I use this code: `SELECT SerialNumber FROM Win32_DiskDrive`.

But this returns every serial number (USB, all drive etc.).

How can I only get the drive where the AppData folder is located?

Comment: Please take a look at one of the previous answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57559814/1410246

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are talking about **serial number** of **physical disk drive**. One way to achieve this as below you can refer to:

1. **Get drive number from path** using [`PathGetDriveNumber`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathgetdrivenumbera?redirectedfrom=MSDN). For example, get `C:` from `AppData` path.
2. **Retrieve the logical disk associated with a given physical disk** using [`Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-diskdrivetodiskpartition) and [`Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-logicaldisktopartition).

[image]

[image]

As snapshots above show, you can get `C:` associated with `PHYSICALDRIVE0`.

3. **Get serial number of the physical disk** using [`Win32_DiskDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-diskdrive).

[image]